# use of for loop counter in if condition php

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, datatables

Below if my code for column search of datatables as well as complete search,

```
$columns = array(0 => 'ship_id' , 
                     1 => 'sr', 
                     2 => 'ce', 
                     3 => 'sto',
                     4 => 'supply' , 
                     5 => 'part',
                     6 => 'description',
                     7 =>  'quantity',
                     8 =>  'date',
                     9 =>  'shipn',
                     10 => 'ship',
                     11 => 'transport', 
                     12 => 'docket',
                     13 => 'delivery');

if(isset($searchValue) && $searchValue != '')
        {
            $searchingAll = array();
            for($i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++) //Loop search in all defined columns
            {
                $searchingAll = $this->db->or_like($columns[$i], $searchValue);
                $searchingColumns = NULL;
            }
        }
        else if($this->input->post('columns[1][search][value]', TRUE) != '')
        {
            for($i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++) //Loop search in all defined columns
            {
                $searchingAll = NULL;
                $searchingColumns = $this->db->or_like($columns[1], $this->input->post('columns[1][search][value]', TRUE));
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $searchingAll = NULL;
            $searchingColumns = NULL;
        }
```

First IF condition will search complete datatable, then else-if will search individual column,

I have 12 columns in my datatables, so i need to loop 12 times else-if condition,

In above code currently i shown only column 1, but i need to check all 12 columns that something is entered in any of column search then it will go to for loop of else-if condition,

How can i check all 12 columns in else-if condition?

Thanks,

Comment: You should look into a full text index for this type of query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

You were not using the `$i` you defined in the `else if`.

Use this instead:

```
    $columns = array(0 => 'ship_id' , 
                 1 => 'sr', 
                 2 => 'ce', 
                 3 => 'sto',
                 4 => 'supply' , 
                 5 => 'part',
                 6 => 'description',
                 7 =>  'quantity',
                 8 =>  'date',
                 9 =>  'shipn',
                 10 => 'ship',
                 11 => 'transport', 
                 12 => 'docket',
                 13 => 'delivery');

    if(isset($searchValue) && $searchValue != '')
    {
        $searchingAll = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++) //Loop search in all defined columns
        {
            $searchingAll = $this->db->or_like($columns[$i], $searchValue);
            $searchingColumns = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if($this->input->post('columns[1][search][value]', TRUE) != '')
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++) //Loop search in all defined columns
        {
            $searchingAll = NULL;
            $searchingColumns = $this->db->or_like($columns[$i], $this->input->post('columns['.$i.'][search][value]', TRUE));
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        $searchingAll = NULL;
        $searchingColumns = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: i know that, but what i want is to have check condition of all 12 columns in else if condition, if anyone is not empty then it will do loop, so i can i check all 12 columns in elseif() condition? currently i used only column1